# Do relative paths in http links are recognized by intent filters in Android?

Tags: android, relative-path, intentfilter

I'm writing intent filter for my `Activity` and I would like to ignore relative paths inside website.

Is this default behavior or it can't be ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to ignore relative paths inside website

When the browser encounters a relative path, the browser will construct a full URL to the resource based upon the URL of the current page and the relative path. The browser will then use that full URL to fulfill the needs for that resource (e.g., loading an image, loading a page based upon a link click).

Whether those full URLs match an `<intent-filter>` of yours is up to you and the Web site author.